# How to obtain the form of sin(nx) and cos(nx) from the result of FourierSeries

Tags: fourier-analysis

How to obtain the form of sin(nx) and cos(nx) from the result of FourierSeries[].

For Example,

$$\text{FourierSeries}[x,x,5]=i e^{-i x}-i e^{i x}-\frac{1}{2} i e^{-2 i x}+\frac{1}{2} i e^{2 i x}+\frac{1}{3} i e^{-3 i x}-\frac{1}{3} i e^{3 i x}-\frac{1}{4} i e^{-4 i x}+\frac{1}{4} i e^{4 i x}+\frac{1}{5} i e^{-5 i x}-\frac{1}{5} i e^{5 i x}$$

How do I obtain the form 
$$a_1 \cos (x)+a_2 \cos (2 x)+a_3 \cos (3 x)+a_4 \cos (4 x)+a_5 \cos (5 x)+a_0+b_1 \sin (x)+b_2 \sin (2 x)+b_3 \sin (3 x)+b_4 \sin (4 x)+b_5 \sin (5 x)$$

from the result of

```
  FourierSeries[x,x,5]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `ExpToTrig[FourierSeries[x, x, 5]]`

Comment: `ComplexExpand@Re@FourierSeries[t, t, 5]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `FourierTrigSeries[x, x, 5]`

If you need just $sin$ or $cos$ terms, `FourierSinSeries` and `FourierCosSeries` do that.

Comment: Very nice,thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ExpToTrig[FourierSeries[x, x, 5]]
```

Comment: That is right,thanks